# Ayuda con un codigo en php para no mostrar la pagina si se accesa desde la url

Tags: php, html, http, referer

tengo el sigueinte codigo que su funcion seria que detectara el ingreso desde la pagina paso1.php  a paso2.php

Me explico, quiero que la gente que ingrese al paso2.php sin pasar por el primer paso no le sea permitido, con este codigo lo he logrado pero tengo un problema que es que no detecta que estoy ingresando desde paso1.php ya que ingreso desde cualqueir otra pagina con enlace a paso2.php y ingresa normalmente cuando tambien deberia mandar el mensaje de error

```
    <?php
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(isset($ref[0])) {
    $protocol = strtolower(parse_url($ref)['scheme']) === 'https' ? 'https':'http';
    echo (strtolower($ref) === $protocol . '://paso1.php') ? 'welcome':'BIENVENIDO, EXITO';  
} else {
   echo 'ERROR HAS INGRESADO POR URL O NO HAS INGRESADO DESDE PASO1.PHP';
}
   ?>
```

Quisiera que el navegador actuara de esta forma: 
(1) si entra por paso1.php SI le permito entrar 
(2) Si entra por URL NO le permino entrar 
(3)Si entra por un enlace desde otra pagina que no sea paso1.php NO le permito entrar.

/// funciona todo menos el (3)

Comment: Pasas de la página paso1 a paso2 con un link? Con un submit?

Comment: Con un submit pero por ahora lo estoy probando con un enlace tipo a href

Comment: Quisiera que el navegador actuara de esta forma: (1) si entra por paso1.php SI le permito entrar (2) Si entra por URL NO le permino entrar (3)Si entra por un enlace desde otra pagina que no sea paso1.php NO le permito entrar. /// funciona todo menos el (3)

Comment: Leyendo los comentarios de la respuesta creo que más bien lo que deberias de buscas y te podrias servir es hacer uso de la variable SESSION ahí podrias almacenar la información de Paso1.php y acceder a ella en Paso2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy sencillo. Puedes colocar un `form` con un `input` oculto como dato de comprobación:

```
<form action="paso2.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="paso1">
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y en tu página `paso2.php` compruebas que se está enviando ese input (puedes cambiar el nombre de `"paso1"` al que tú quieras y deberás colocar el mismo en la página `paso2.php`). Ya en la página `paso2.php` solo comprobamos que está llegando ese `POST` y colocamos al inicio de todo este código:

```
<?php 
    //Aquí se comprueba que venga de paso1.php
    if(!isset($_POST["paso1"])){
       //Cualquier acción en caso de que no venga de paso1.php
        echo "Solo se puede acceder por paso1.php";
        die();
    }else{
        echo "Entró desde paso1.php";
    }
?>
```

---

Para comprobar si viene de una url específica solo debes colocar esto en tu archivo `paso2.php` al inicio del archivo:

```
<?php
    $carpeta = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
    $ruta = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$carpeta/paso1.php";
    $aux = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
    $referer = substr($aux, 0, strpos($aux, '?'));

    if($referer !== $ruta){
            echo "Solo se puede acceder por paso1.php";
            die();
        }else{
            echo "Entró desde paso1.php";
        }
    ?>
```

La ruta tiene que ser algo parecido a esto:

```
http://localhost/folder/paso1.php
```

Comment: Excelente amigo me sirvio, en este caso como haria cuando ingreso desde un enlace? por ejemplo

Comment: lo he hecho pero haga lo que haga siempre me muestra "Solo se puede acceder por paso1.php"  coloque la ruta como me dijiste y el enlace desde paso1.php  <a href="paso2.php">ir a paso2</a>

Comment: Ve a paso1.php y copia la url y la pegas tal y como está, quizá cambia el http por https

Comment: Si eso hice de esta forma `http://localhost/referer/paso1.php` pero aun me manda el mensaje de error "Solo se puede acceder por paso1.php"

Comment: Acabo de editar de nuevo porque me fijé que no se puso un parte del código. Y tiene que tener http:// o htpps:// antes del localhost

Comment: Listo hermano excelente ahora otra pregunta y disculpa, como haria si por ejemplo paso1.php tiene variables en la URL ejemplo:  `paso1.php?nombre=carlos&apellido=medina `  como haria para que siguiera detectando que ingreso desde paso1.php y no afecte el resto de la URL

Comment: O si quieres hacerlo por lo de la URL, puedes cortar la cadena $referer con la función substr(), cortan a partir de "?..."

Comment: lo que pasa es que si envia la variable del primer metodo con GET por la URL el usuario con tener el link podra entrar siempre y necesito que la unica forma que entre sea pasando primero por paso1.php pero el problema es que paso1.php tiene variables ya desde el inicio `paso1.php?nombre=carlos&apellido=medina` quisiera que detectara que ingreso desde paso1.php sin ver las variables de la URL

Comment: donde colocaria la función `substr()` en el codigo que me has pasado , gracais hermano no sabes cuanto me has ayudado.

Comment: Acabo de modificar el código, solo asegurate de cambiar en $ruta el https por http o viceversa

Comment: Gracias amigo pero me sirve de la misma forma que antes, si entro desde `http://localhost/referer/paso1.php` me da el mensaje de bienvenida pero si entro desde `http://localhost/referer/paso1.php?nombre=carlos&apellido=medina` me manda el mensaje de error "Solo se puede acceder por paso1.php"

Comment: Disculpa por tanto preguntar, pero sera posible solucionar lo del comentario anterior? seria ya lo ultimo gracias hermano.

Comment: Listo, lo que debes cambiar es: el $referer pasa a ser $aux, $referer es la cadena cortada de la url de procedencia desde el inicio hasta el momento donde encuentra "?"

Comment: Muy bien hermano si me sirvio excelente, otra pregunta por ejemplo se puede agregar varias rutas por ejemplo solo pueda entrar desde paso1.php paso0.php etc

Comment: ¿Desde paso0 a paso2? o de paso0 a paso1? Si es de paso0 a paso1 sería el mismo procedimiento, si es de paso0 a paso2 debes agregar otra variable con el path (ruta) y en vez de paso1.php al final colocas paso0.php y en el if colocas las dos condiciones (Investiga: disyunción lógica)

Comment: No me refiero los mismos permisos para entrar a paso2.php sea siempre y cuando se ingrese desde paso1.php o paso0.php etc

Comment: Te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta detallando mejor lo que tienes y lo que quieres, la verdad no te entiendo y quizá haya otro que te pueda ayudar :)